# How can I use AVAssetExportSession to overwrite songs in my iPhone/iPod library?

Tags: iphone, file-io, ios4, iphone-4, mpmediaitemcollection

So supposedly in the iOS 4 SDK you can edit and write to the user's iTunes library. I can successfully load an AVAsset from my iPhone/iPod library, but as a quick test I'm trying to just overwrite the same file right away using AVAssetExportSession but it's always returning the status "4" which I **THINK** is AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed... In the documentation it says:

```
enum {
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting
};
```

but in AVAssetExportSession.h it says:

```
enum {
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed,
    AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled
};
typedef NSInteger AVAssetExportSessionStatus;
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// before this, i'm using mpmediapicker to pick an m4a file i synched with my itunes library 

NSURL *assetUrl = [[self.userMediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: assetUrl options: nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: asset presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
exportSession.outputURL = asset.URL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

NSLog(@"output filetype: %@", exportSession.outputFileType);
// prints "com.apple.m4a-audio"

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void) {
    NSLog(@"status: %i for %@", exportSession.status, exportSession.outputURL);
    // prints "status: 4 for ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=3631988601206299774"
}];

[exportSession release];
```

So either way... I guess it's "failed" or "cancelled." Has anyone else successfully written to the media library before?

Thanks!

Comment: if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed) NSLog(@"failed");
if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled) NSLog(@"cancelled");
Are you sure that you are allowed to overwrite?

Comment: Also `NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", exportSession.error);` should help.

Comment: thanks, looks like it's failing. so that's half the battle. the other half is finding out why! :) i wonder if there's some way that I can save out a new file to the user dir and then add it to the library instead of writing directly to the asset.URL url. hmm...

Comment: what does `NSLog(@"ExportSessionError: %@", [exportSession.error localizedDescription])` say?

Comment: ExportSessionError: The operation couldn’t be completed. (AVFoundationErrorDomain error -11800.) :(

Comment: looks like a sandbox issue - i guess apple doesn't let you modify any ipod-library:// items. bummer.

Comment: I think this [link][1] works for you whet you want...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802288/songs-imported-from-ipod-library-not-working-for-ios-5-1-but-works-fine-for-5-0/9806135#9806135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot write to itunes library, only read from it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSParameterAssert(library);
if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL     fileURLWithPath:movieFileName]]) {
   [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieFileName]     completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){}];
}
[library release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, sorry I wasn't more clear: I'd like to write audio files to the user's music library.