# Songs imported from ipod Library not working for iOS 5.1 but Works fine for 5.0 and later OS

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, ios5.1

i have implemented code [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077725/application-crashed-while-importing-songs-from-ipod-library-in-iphone-for-ios-5/9771923#9771923)

but it's not working for iOS 5.0, it will not storing file to document directory like other later OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653241/get-error-code-11843-while-exporting-mp3-file-in-ipod-library-since-ios-5-1)

really it's nice solution given by Albert.